# How do you use psql client to connect to a postgresql ipv6 host?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, psql

```
# postgresql.conf
listen_addresses='::'
```

and

```
# pg_hba.conf
hostssl  webdb  webserver   ::0/0    cert
```

The postgresql server is running on docker with pingable ipv6 address of `"GlobalIPv6Address": "fe80::242:ac12:2"` - so no firewalls obstructing.

I am using the following command to connect

```
psql --command="select * from test;" -d webdb -h fe80::242:ac12:2 -p 5432 -U postgres
psql: could not connect to server: Invalid argument
    Is the server running on host "fe80::242:ac12:2" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Why is the host not recognized? Is it not possible to use ipv6 with psql? Also, I did not find an ssl parameter option in psql.

Comment: Is the Postgres service started?

Comment: Yes. It's started. Was able to run selects by logging into the running docker container.

Comment: fe80::/10 are link-local addresses, can't be used without specifiying their interface. This is not related to psql, ping6 on that address would presumably produce the same error ("Invalid argument")

Comment: @DanielVérité You are right. I did specify the interface while using ping6. How do I specify the interface for psql?

Comment: On Unix, `%interface` as a suffix to the ipv6 address. Windows uses numbers instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Daniel Vérité mentioned in the comment, on Unix, "%interface" should be given as a suffix to the ipv6 address. You can get the interfaces by running ifconfig command. So, the right psql command was

```
psql --command="select * from test;" -d webdb -h fe80::242:ac12:2%br-67d2c47f5b8e -p 5432 -U webserver
```

I had other problems. But now, the host was reachable. Next, I noticed that the suffix "clientcert = 1" had to be added to pg_hba.conf (don't know why)

```
# pg_hba.conf
hostssl  webdb  webserver   ::0/0    cert clientcert=1
```

listen_addresses value in postgresql.conf was fine (restricting requests & responses to only ipv6 addresses) - so is the value '::0/0' in pg_hba.conf

I then got ssl validation errors from the server. I had to set path variables on my client side for psql.

```
export PGSSLCERT=/my-folder/my-certificate.pem
export PGSSLKEY=/my-folder/my-private-key.pem
```

If your private key is password protected, psql prompts you for the password. Once the connection went through, (=> ssl works fine) , I noticed that the role "webserver" didn't have login permission. I had to [alter-role](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-alterrole.html) to allow login and had to [grant](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-grant.html) select and update access to the test table.

Now it works. Thanks to Daniel for the ipv6 suffix solution.

Answer (score 0):

To make postgres avaliable in your network, you need to configure the `listen_addresses` to `*`.

Then you adjust the `pg_hba.conf`[2] to allow connection from your host. E.g:

```
hostssl  webdb  webserver   fe80::242:ac12:2/128    cert
```

After ajust the files, reload the postgres server.

Please, see the doc[1] about more authentication errors.

Hope it helps.

References:

1. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication-problems.html
2. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html
3. http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/STCMML8/com.ibm.storage.ts3500.doc/opg_3584_IPv4_IPv6_prefix_subnet_mask.html

Comment: I just had to use <ipv6-address>%<interface> to make it connect to the database. My pg-hba.conf needed the "clientcert = 1" suffix. The rest was fine - i.e. I wanted to allow all ipv6 addresses - hence "::0/0" in pg_hba.conf